# managing sockets in connect()ing to multiple hosts

Tags: c, sockets

I have a program that works like a server(`listen()`s, `bind()`s, and `accept()`s multiple connections from the same programs in other IPs), and at the same time take user inputs like a UNIX shell.

The user inputs are for commands, and there's a command `CONNECT` with address and port number specification.

I want to make it connect to multiple hosts, and I guess I have to use one socket for each connection.

As I create sockets upon `CONNECT` request from user, how can I manage these sockets?

Should I use a global `array` of sockets and create and add sockets to it as I make connections?

Comment: post code about what ever you tried so far.

Comment: yeah, it will be tricky. You'll either need a thread for each socket or master select() to wait on multiple sockets.

Comment: I'm managing connections that it has `accept()`ed using `select()` already. I need a way to manage sockets for hosts it is `connect()`ed to.

Comment: This sounds very confused. You already have a confused piece of software that is both a TCP server and a user interface, and now you want to turn it into a TCP client as well? Ot should only be doing two of these things at most: user interface and client. Servers don't have user interfaces. Rethink, redesign.

Comment: @EJP Right, but that's the specification for my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you want to manage multiple client in server.  right?

So you have to take some predefined array of sockets globally and then serve each one

ex.

```
long accept_sock[10];//This should be global
                     //initilize it with -1 at entry point
while(1)
{
    struct sockaddr   client;  /* for BSDish accept() call */
    int               clientsize;
    clientsize = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    long sock ;

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        if(accept_sock[i] == -1)
        {    
            sock= accept(server_sock, &client, &clientsize);

            if(sock != -1)
            {
                acepct_sock[i] =sock;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        if(accept_sock[i] != -1)
        {    
          //do process 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I think you need Concurrent Servers.There are two main classes of servers, iterative and concurrent. An iterative server iterates through each client, handling it one at a time. A concurrent server handles multiple clients at the same time. The simplest technique for a concurrent server is use select/fork(). 


 #define FD_SETSIZE 20   /* MAX number of client */

  for (i = 0; i < FD_SETSIZE; i++)
                client[i] = -1;
        FD_ZERO(&allset);
        FD_SET(listenfd, &allset);

        for ( ; ; ) {
                rset = allset;
                nready = select(maxfd+1, &rset, NULL, NULL, NULL);

                if (FD_ISSET(listenfd, &rset)) {        /* new client connection */
                        printf("listening socket readable\n");
                        clilen = sizeof(cliaddr);
                        connfd = accept(listenfd, (SA *) &cliaddr, &clilen);

                        for (i = 0; i < FD_SETSIZE; i++)
                                if (client[i] < 0) {
                                        client[i] = connfd;     /* save descriptor */
                                        break;
                                }
                        if (i == FD_SETSIZE)
                                printf("too many clients");

                        FD_SET(connfd, &allset);        /* add new descriptor to set */
                        if (connfd > maxfd)
                                maxfd = connfd;                 /* for select */
                        if (i > maxi)
                                maxi = i;                               /* max index in client[] array */

                        if (--nready <= 0)
                                continue;                               /* no more readable descriptors */
                }

                for (i = 0; i <= maxi; i++) {   /* check all clients for data */
                         if ( (sockfd = client[i]) < 0)
                                continue;
                        if (FD_ISSET(sockfd, &rset)) {
                                /* do process */
                        }
                }
        }
```